# Linux kernel module to monitor a particular process

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I would like to write a kernel module in Linux that can monitor all the memory accesses made by a particular process(that I specify by name in the kernel module). I would also like to keep track of all the signals generated by the process and log all memory accesses that result in page faults, and memory accesses that cause a TRAP or a SEGV. How could I go about doing this? Could you point me towards any resources that could get me started off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you have never written a kernel module before this might be a great start:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180901094541/http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux?page=0%2C2

From there you basically wan't to grab process information and output it, perhaps create some kind of /proc device..

But you should know this isn't really something you need kernel mode for. You could probably do this easily right from user space.

Comment: What would you use to do it from userspace, ptrace?

Comment: getrusage() and a few other syscalls. Ptrace could be an option but that would be more if you need process state.